# how to use pagination with search option in laravel using eloquent ORM?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

query works but it does not show search results i.e where condition is not working?

```
function (Request $request)
{
    $clientname =$request['clientname'];  //for scanning the input throught postman. 
    $users = paginationModel::where('clientname','like','%'.$clientname.'%')->paginate(2);
}
```

Comment: how about `$clientname = trim($request->clientname)`

Answer (score 0):

query is correct it works.I made a mistake in postman while giving inputs instead of using form data field .
I had given inputs in headers field.